# Why did Bill tell Loraine the riddle?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-conjuring-universe, the-conjuring-2

Why did Bill Wilkins tell Loraine the riddle she used in figuring the name of the demon?

I thought the old man's spirit was controlled by Valak.

Comment: Which riddle, and when was this? I saw the movie a few months ago and the details are fuzzy

Comment: The riddle "am giving and am taking.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they explained in the movie that Wilkins' soul was being held hostage by Valak instead of moving on, so Wilkins gets the riddle out so that his soul can be released and he can be at peace. He was basically struggling against Valak's control to get the riddle out, which is why he said it over more than one session, and said it backwards.